# dhcpcd can't startup at boot

Tags: arch-linux, dhcp, systemd

when I run `dhcpcd` after boot everything works fine but when I try to add it to auto start `systemctl enable dhcpcd@eth0.service`, after each boot it's inactive

```
dhcpcd@eth0.service       loaded inactive dead      start dhcpcd on eth0
```

Comment: What happens if you simply do 'systemctl enable dhcpcd' ?

Comment: the same, symbolic link is created, service starts but it's dead. I run Arch Linux in VirtualBox on Windows 7 if that matters.

Comment: systemctl status dhcpcd@eth0.service? Shows any error message?

Comment: Ohh, I didn't try this command. Yes, it says no such file or directory.

Comment: @don_crissti: thanks, changing name worked for me ;)

Answer (score 12):

`systemctl enable dhcpcd.service` works for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @jasonwryan Although you don't think it is an answer, it is the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the ethernet device name is not `eth0`. Mine is `enp3s0`. This varies with the ethernet device.